# How to fix Python import error for Crypto.Signature.DSS

Tags: python, import, pycharm, pycrypto, pycryptodome

I am trying to run the `pycryptodome` [example](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/public_key/dsa.html) for DSA. Here is the example code:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import DSA
from Crypto.Signature import DSS
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256

# Create a new DSA key
key = DSA.generate(2048)
f = open("public_key.pem", "w")
f.write(key.publickey().export_key())
f.close()

# Sign a message
message = b"Hello"
hash_obj = SHA256.new(message)
signer = DSS.new(key, 'fips-186-3')
signature = signer.sign(hash_obj)
```

But I am facing `ImportError` for `DSS`. Here is the error output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/snap/pycharm-professional/154/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "/snap/pycharm-professional/154/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/home/username/Projects/DSA_Example.py", line 2, in <module>
    from Crypto.Signature import DSS
ImportError: cannot import name 'DSS'
```

My development environment includes:

- Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
- Python 3.6.8
- PyCharm IDE 2019.2
- Using `venv` Python virtual environment
- `pip list` command shows:

```
    (venv) username@myubuntu:~/Projects/MyProject/$ pip list
    DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.
    asn1crypto (0.24.0)
    cryptography (2.1.4)
    decorator (4.1.2)
    enum34 (1.1.6)
    idna (2.6)
    ipaddress (1.0.17)
    keyring (10.6.0)
    keyrings.alt (3.0)
    networkx (1.11)
    numpy (1.13.3)
    pip (9.0.1)
    pycrypto (2.6.1)
    pycryptodome (3.9.0)
    pygobject (3.26.1)
    pyxdg (0.25)
    PyYAML (3.12)
    rubber (1.4)
    SecretStorage (2.3.1)
    setuptools (39.0.1)
    six (1.11.0)
    wheel (0.30.0)
```

Now how do I fix the import error for DSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you also have pycrypto (2.6.1) installed which also has a module named Crypto.Signature.  What is happening is that Python is trying to import pycrypto.Crypto.Signature (which does not have a DSS module) instead of pycryptodome.Crypto.Signature. To fix this you could try running 
`pip uninstall pycrypto` and see if that fixes your issue.

Note on the install page for [pycryptodome](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/installation.html) it says "One must avoid having both PyCrypto and PyCryptodome installed at the same time, as they will interfere with each other".